# Xamarin UWP App Store Submission gives error code 1201

Tags: xamarin, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store, xamarin.uwp

I am trying to submit a UWP Xamarin Forms app to the Windows store. Everything checks out fine locally. I pass the WACK test (Windows Application Certification Kit) both locally as well as during submission. But during the submission process, I get a cryptic 1201 without any additional information. How can I get additional details to fix this issue.

Looking at some of the posts online, I removed ARM and only submitted an x64 bundle. That seemed to work fine the first time. But when I try and update the submission, I am getting error 1201.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

BTW, I am using VS2019, Xamarin Forms 5.0.0.2083

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please contacted reportap@microsoft.com for detailed error messages first.

Comment: Hi @RoyLi-MSFT. I did create a support request. No luck whatsoever with that person. In fact, I don't even think she is reading the messages because she sends very generic responses to my queries.  I did try and create a repro based on her request and that gives me a new set of errors.

Comment: Does a blank Xamarin forms app show the same behavior?

Comment: Hi Roy. No, I did not try a blank app yet. I am however working with the App support group. I created a Repro and they could not find any issues with it. It is suggested that there may be a memory issue in the compilation. I have been able to submit the app updates intermittently (try 3-4 times or more and then it miraculously succeeds). Will try the 64Bit Build Option as suggested to see if it goes away.

Comment: Good. Glad to hear you could submit it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about an app store submission system.

Comment: Not sure why you would close this question just because it is about an app store submission process. This issue has been faced by multiple windows store app developers. In any case, solutions have been found for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not on my end but more to do with the idiosyncrasies of submission process in the Windows Store.  I still get sporadic issues but I have resolved it with a combination of the following compiler flags:

1. Setting the Use64BitCompiler msbuild property to avoid memory issues
2. true
3. Ensuring that the release build is clean and working

I will update this answer as I learn more in my subsequent submissions.